# Big try-catch block in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, try-catch

Is it a good practice to use a big try-catch block in JavaScript in order to enclose all the code inside jQuery's document ready event?

Some coworkers write code like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    try{
        //tons of code
    }
    catch(err){
        //post-exception statements
    }
});
```

So they handle any errors thrown in code

Is this approach the right one? If not, How should I handle errors in JavaScript? And in asynchronous functions, how do I handle errors in callbacks? Especially in document ready.

Comment: This is a bad approach. You should not be wrapping your code in a giant try block (if there's an error then you should fix it instead of catching it!) Error handling is another business. If you are talking about errors such as a timeout in XHR or other errors in any async function, most likely they will provide a parameter for callback functions.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I know I should fix any error, but when it comes to know that an error occurred and for example I want to log it, what should I do?

Comment: Probably not a great idea, but it depends on a number of factors.  If the risk of exceptions is extremely low and you have little or no time for testing and developing error-handling code, then this is what you may have to go with.

Comment: @jecarfor Use the developer console for debugging. It provides a lot of information including setting breakpoints for further investigations.

Comment: If you want to log a client-side error, you'll need to put code in the catch block to post it to the server, and have the server log it.

Answer (score 3):

I think most of the developers using try catch in JavaScript comes from language where try-catch block is common, like Java.

In JavaScript, even if it supported, it has a lot of drawbacks.

For example, it does not catch any asynchronous callbacks even if the callback itself is lexically defined inside the try-catch block.

This [link](https://dev.opera.com/articles/efficient-javascript/?page=2#trycatch) will provide you some answers about why it is not recommended to abuse try catch in your JS code.

I find that one of the major drawbacks is that JS engines like V8 won't optimize (for the moment) any bit of codes inside try-catch.

*Thought :*
For my side, I'm used to only use try catch around code like

```
var x = JSON.parse(string);
```

and ONLY if the result of such operation is not mandatory for the good operation of the rest of the program, as there is no real error handler alternative for such operations (if it fails, the code ceases to work).

Comment: >> For example, it does not catch any asynchronous callbacks even if the callback itself is lexically defined inside the try-catch block.
<< Good poInt. That's because try..catch works synchronously.